# filepath.Join removes dot

Tags: go, filepath

i have a problem with create path for rsync.

```
x := filepath.Join("home", "my_name", "need_folder", ".")
fmt.Println(x)
```

I get `"home/my_name/need_folder"`, but need `"home/my_name/need_folder/."`, how fix without concat? In linux folder with name "." not impossible.

Thank you!

Comment: That's not true, in Linux a folder with name "." is impossible, because "." is a reserved name indicating the current directory. So "/home/my_name/need_folder/." is exactly equivalent to "/home/my_name/need_folder".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do that with the [`filepath.Join()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Join) as its documentation states:

> Join calls Clean on the result...

And since `.` denotes the "current" directory, it will be removed by [`filepath.Clean()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Clean):

> It applies the following rules iteratively until no further processing can be done:
>
> 1. [...]
> 2. Eliminate each . path name element (the current directory).

And in fact you can't do what you want with the [`path/filepath`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/) package at all, there is no support for this operation.

You need to use string concatenation manually. Use `filepath.Separator` for it, it'll be safe:

```
x := filepath.Join("home", "my_name", "need_folder") +
    string(filepath.Separator) + "."
fmt.Println(x)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EWrAy1Coybh)):

```
home/my_name/need_folder/.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke filepath.Join it actually has two steps

1. concat the path with separator, by this step actually you will get "home/my_name/need_folder/."
2. clean the path, which will do a lexical processing on the `path` and return the shortest path name equal to the `path` you get in step 1.

In step 2, if you read the source code you will find, it invokes a `Clean` function and the function will

> Eliminate each . path name element (the current directory).

And you can try:

`x := filepath.Join("home", "my_name", "need_folder", ".", "." , ".")
fmt.Println(x)`

you will still get the same result.

If suggest you use concat in this case :)