# join paths with backslash separator independent of the underlying os with the standard library

Tags: go

[filepath.Join](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Join) allows to join paths by using the path separator of the underlying os (basically `\` on Windows, `/` everywhere else).

Is there a way to **force** using the Windows path separator `\` for joining paths with the Go standard library no matter what the actual running operating system is?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you are developping in Linux/any-non-windows-OS for Windows, cross-compilation will handle this for you, as when cross-compiled, `filepath.Join()` will use the target OS separator, not the building OS one.

Comment: @Adirio I am creating a client for an existing SOAP service I don't have any influence on, and the remote service accepts a Windows path only.

Comment: Okey, sounds legit. I was wondering if it was just a missunderstanding about cross-compilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not with the standard lib's [`path/filepath`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/) package. You have to use [`strings.Join()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join) instead.

If you do rely on "side-effects" of [`filepath.Join()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Join) (e.g. adding a separator if necessary, calling `Clean()` etc.), then easiest would be to call `filepath.Join()`, then replace slashes with backslashes, e.g. using [`strings.ReplaceAll()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ReplaceAll).

Note that the replace-all method works because slash `/` is a reserved character and cannot appear in names other than separating folders and files. For details, see [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file).

See related [filepath.Join removes dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669486/filepath-join-removes-dot/51670536#51670536).